# ufw and iptables rules

Tags: ufw

I have Ubuntu 22.04 running with ufw enabled. For some testing reason I disabled ufw but found that after reboot the rules are active again.

Since ufw is not enabled the old rules are applied to iptables.

How is that possible?

How to get rid of these old rules?

Who is responsible for loading the old rules?